# How to wait for a query to return results?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to have a query wait until it has results instead of returning immediately with an empty result set. For example:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1
```

If `Table1` is empty, the query would return with an empty result set. However, I want it to not return, but wait until at least one row is available, preferably with a timeout of some sort. I would prefer to do this without involving Service Broker into the equation, if possible.

**Clarification:**

CLR is enabled on the server, but the call is coming from a platform independent C++ program via SQLAPI++/ODBC. So, no C#/.NET tricks are possible. The goal is to make a call into a stored procedure, specify a timeout and not return until data is available (and returned by the stored proc) or the specified timeout expires.

For example:

```
EXEC GetData @Timeout=2000 -- Wait for upto 5000 milliseconds for a result set to be 
                           -- available
```

Comment: clr enabled can be used ? ( c# code...) ?

Comment: clr is enabled on the server and can be used from within a stored proc call. (calling code is platform independent code that uses the SQLAPI++ library for DB access via ODBC, so not much flexibility on the calling side)

Comment: Sounds like something service broker and `WAITFOR` was designed for. Why the reluctance to use it?

Comment: Complexity and maintenance issues. We're not using Service Broker at the moment and noone is well versed in its maintenance, so I am reluctant to introduce it at the present time. A DBMS neutral implementation is also preferable, but I realize that that may not be possible in this case. However, a command would be easier to wrap than a dependency on Service Broker.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn cant you create a trigger after insert and in that trigger - run a clr function which callis inproc service of your c# proram which in-turn - read by command the db ?

Comment: In TSQL you can capture the current date/time, run the `select` with output to a temporary table or table variable, and check for results.  If there are no results and your timeout has not expired then wait and loop, otherwise `select` the temporary results.  Ugly, but simple and more or less portable.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but effective.  As long as the query being executed is low cost, e.g. waiting for rows to appear in an empty table, this shouldn't be too much of a resource swine.

```
declare @Timeout as Int = 5000 -- Milliseconds.

-- Start and end times.
declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate()
declare @TimeoutExpiration as DateTime = DateAdd( ms, @Timeout, @Now )

-- Set the delay interval to the smaller of  @Timeout / 10   or   1 second.
declare @DelayInterval as Time = DateAdd( ms, @Timeout / 10, 0 )
if @DelayInterval > '00:00:01.000'
  set @DelayInterval = '00:00:01.000'
declare @WaitForDelay as VarChar(12) = Cast( @DelayInterval as VarChar(12) )  -- WaitFor insists on a truncated string for the delay.

select @Timeout as 'Timeout (ms)', @Now as 'Now', @TimeoutExpiration as 'TimeoutExpiration', @DelayInterval as 'DelayInterval'

declare @Result as Table ( Foo Int ) -- Modify to match the schema of your expected results.

-- Execute the query in a loop until either a result is returned or the timeout expires.
declare @RowCount as Int = 0
declare @Iterations as Int = 0
while @TimeoutExpiration >= GetDate() and @RowCount = 0
  begin
  -- Randomly decide to insert a row into the results.  (Replace with your query.)
  insert into @Result
    select 42 as Foo
      where Rand() > 0.8
  -- Handle the query result.
  set @RowCount = @@RowCount
  if @RowCount = 0
    waitfor delay @WaitForDelay
  set @Iterations = @Iterations + 1
  end

-- Return the result.
select @Iterations as 'Iterations' -- Just for demonstration purposes.
select *
  from @Result
```